# Responsive positioned image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I was wondering how I can make a series of positioned images respond to the window's dimension? I'm not quite sure as if the images themselves need to be relative and have the page wrap absolute or the other way around. I have been playing around on jsfiddle but nothing seems to be working. For reference, the following website accomplishes the effect I would like to create--it responds completely to the windows width: http://www.index-std.com/ressources/projets/guillaume_lorieux.html

I have set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/uz41Leno/

Many thanks in advance!

**CSS:**

```
.a { top:0; left:20%; height:300px; }
.b { top:150px; right:0; height:250px; }
.c { top:400px; left:0; height:200px; }
.d { top:600px; left:50%; height:100px; }
.e { top:900px; right:20%; height:300px; }
.f { top:800px; left:10%; height:200px; }
.g { top:1300px; left:0; height:300px; }
.a, .b, .c, .d, .e, .f, .g { width:auto; }

div.page {  }
img { width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; }
figure.thumbnail { width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; }
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page">
    <figure class="thumbnail">
        <img class="a" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/fxqe6g.jpg"/>
        <img class="b" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2wgeutv.jpg"/>
        <img class="c" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/dptspl.jpg"/>
        <img class="d" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2dv8mj6.jpg"/>
        <img class="e" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/208u109.jpg"/>
        <img class="f" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2qdpvly.jpg"/>
        <img class="g" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2u4ljmd.jpg"/>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into media queries?

Comment: Hi rp.beltran -- what do you mean by media queries?

Comment: They are blocks of CSS that are only applied when the screen meets certain conditions (usually based on size and device type). http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp covers them pretty well. They might work for you depending on you goals, but I think you might want a more continuous solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/uz41Leno/1/). Essentially, you need to get rid of static size declarations and do more relative/dynamic sizing like `max-width` instead of `width`.

If you're looking to do more things like what your example site does, i.e., have all the images fly around after being resized, that's more of a javascript-looking solution.

**EDIT**

In the given example, the author wraps his images in a div and sets the width and position to a percentage of the container. When the container shrinks, so does the wrapper. With the image set at 100%, the image will shrink accordingly.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thank you for the edit, but I think there was a slight mix-up. If you look at http://www.index-std.com/ressources/projets/guillaume_lorieux.html ,the images maintain their position and not collide each other. Can this be done through CSS only?

Comment: yes. use px for position instead of percentages. there's no mixup, i know exactly what you're trying to do ;) if you watch container element of that site in dev tools, you'll see that the divs are absolutely positioned with px units, then after you resize the page, javascript repositions them.

Comment: Hmm, I changed percentage to px but it doesn't seem to maintain its position and respond to the window's width. Can you take a look at it? http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/uz41Leno/2/

Comment: oh i see what they're doing. so he has a container around his images that has a width and position relative to the container size. the image inside is width 100%. sorry for taking you down the wrong path. wrap each of your images accordingly and put percentage widths and positions on them and you should see a similar effect. however, like i said before, they will position themselves on top of each other, you need JS to move them around after resizing

Comment: Ah I see, sorry about the confusion -- that was my bad! Yeah, I took a peek at their CSS, but I was hoping to resolve this issue with CSS only. (Also, it looks like he uses CSS to assign the placements of the images. I seems to be that the JS scripts serve an animation function). Thoughts on the possibility of achieving the effect with CSS only?

Comment: it could be possible with mediaqueries, as @rp.beltran suggested. at certain viewport sizes, adjust the percentages accordingly. if you put transitions on your properties, you'll get your animations too. good luck!